# Regex finds pattern

Tags: regex

how can I find by using regular expression the "c start" pattern which is multiple times addressed. In other words, this should find only when this pattern is found more than once. Below is an example of an xml, which shows twice the "c start", so I would like to know what is the regex in order to find it?

```
  <c start="11111" end="1111111" />
  <c start="11111" end="222222222" />
</action>
<action
  src="abc"
  system="2222">
  <param
    name="trackID"
    value="1"
    valueType="data">
  </param>
  <param
    name="trackName"
    value="track"
    valueType="data">
  </param>
  <c start="11111" end="1111111" />
  <c start="11111" end="222222222" />
```

I may have the following xml which doesn't have more that once the pattern.

```
  <c start="11111" end="1111111" />
</action>
<action
  src="abc"
  system="2222">
  <param
    name="trackID"
    value="1"
    valueType="data">
  </param>
  <param
    name="trackName"
    value="track"
    valueType="data">
  </param>
  <c start="11111" end="1111111" />
```

Comment: Please specify what's your desired result.

Comment: /(<c start=[\s\S]*){2,}/g should do it

Comment: Please update your question accordingly. Have you been through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What did you try so far?

Comment: @PoulBak this doesn't match

Comment: I would advise you to use an XML-parser instead, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 (also applies to XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this:

`<c\s+start=\"(?<start>[^\"]+)\"\s+end=\"(?<end>[^\"]+)\"\s+\/>`

This expression has two groups named as `start` and `end` to retrieve values from quotes.

But you can use `<c\s+start=\"([^\"]+)\"\s+end=\"([^\"]+)\"\s+\/>` if you don't need named groups.

You can check your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: if I need to embed it to a bash script, how do I have to write it?